# Alternative to a while loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to develop my understanding of php and would really appreciate any help. I have used a while loop to compare some values posted in my form with what is stored in a csv file.
This code works well. However, is it possible to achieve the same result using a FOR EACH loop or even a Do Until?? Or both?? Many thanks for any support

```
$file_handle = fopen("games.csv", "r"); # identify which file is being used.
while(!feof($file_handle))
{
$gameinfo = fgetcsv($file_handle);
if ($gameinfo[0] == $_POST["gameID"])
{
$GameName = "$gameinfo[2]";
$GameCost = "$gameinfo[4]";
$GameFound = true;
}
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: No, for reading from a file handle while is the only sensible construct.  Foreach requires knowing the size of the structure to loop over ahead of time and do... while is always going to execute at least one loop, even if the file is 0 length.

Comment: I might be inclined to break out of the loop once you've found the game, rather than continue looping.... and why are you wrapping `$gameinfo[2]` and `$gameinfo[4]` in quotes (`"`)

Comment: @GordonM Ah I see, so the for each loop would be impossible to determine the number of iterations.  However, why would it be bad for the do while to execute the loop at least once even if the file is 0 length - do you mean that the program is just wasting time??

Comment: @Mark Baker Good point!!! I need to use Break!

Comment: Yeah, if the file is zero bytes long (and therefore consists of nothing but an EOF marker) then there's nothing for the loop to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while` is the best suited statement for this task, because you want to check for *EOF* before doing any read.

You can transform it in a `do-while` (there is no `do-until` in PHP) as an exercise:

```
do
{
   if (!feof($file_handle))
   {
      $gameinfo = fgetcsv($file_handle);

      if ($gameinfo[0] == $_POST["gameID"])
      {
         ...
      }
   }
}
while(!feof($file_handle));
```

or shorter

```
do
{
   if (feof($file_handle))
      break;

   $gameinfo = fgetcsv($file_handle);

   if ($gameinfo[0] == $_POST["gameID"])
   {
      ...
   }
}
while(true);
```

but that's just a bad way to write a `while`.

Regarding [foreach](https://secure.php.net/manual/it/control-structures.foreach.php), quoting the doc

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.

You can [customize iteration over objects](https://secure.php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.iterations.php), this let you (**Warning**, layman language) use `foreach` on "custom objects" so that you can, in a way, extend the functionality of `foreach`.
For example to iterate over CSV files you can use this class

```
<?php
class FileIterator implements Iterator
{
    private $file_handle = null;
    private $file_name;
    private $line;

    public function __construct($file_name)
    {
        $this->file_name = $file_name;

        $this->rewind();
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->file_handle))
            fclose($this->file_handle);

        $this->line = 1;
        $this->file_handle = fopen($this->file_name, "r");
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return fgetcsv($this->file_handle);
    }

    public function key() 
    {
        return $this->line;
    }

    public function next() 
    {
        return $this->line++;
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        $valid = !feof($this->file_handle);

        if (!$valid)
           fclose($this->file_handle);

        return $valid;
    }

}
?>
```

and use it this way

```
$it = new FileIterator("game.csv");

foreach ($it as $line => $gameObj) 
{
    echo "$line: " . print_r($gameObj, true) . "<br/>";
}
```

Which produce something like

```
1: Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => Far Cry 3 ) 
2: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Far Cry Primal ) 
3: Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => Alien Isolation )
```

for this file

```
0,Far Cry 3
1,Far Cry Primal
2,Alien Isolation
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question in such detail. The for each will take me a little time to get my head around but really appreciate it

Comment: I suppose you could use file () and foreach over that as another way of doing it `foreach (file ("file_name_goes_here") as $line)` but that means loading the entire file into memory to create the array.  Big file = big memory usage.

Comment: @MissDizy Extending the previous comment, there is an even simpler way (thanks to http://se1.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#114764): `foreach (array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv')))`.